# Storing IdentityDbContext in separate database, redudance?

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, dbcontext

I've got some thoughts regarding ASP.NET Identity for my backend.

I've stored my IdentityDbContext as a separate database using SqlLite.

I therefore have my own dbcontext: "BaseDbContext", as well as "IdentityDbContext".

My own db-context is registered on a separate database, since I don't want to be tied up to identity's structure.

HOWEVER, I have one question regarding this: If I want to connect users to other tables and keep track of actions etc, should I have my own "tblUser" alongside Identity, or how would this work in practise?

So basically my structure looks like the following:

**IdentityDb:**

- AspNetUsers
- AspNetRoles
- etc ..

**BaseDb:**

- tblProject
- tblTask
- tblUser ????

I've previously used a custom datastore within Identity, but it's a lot to rewrite and wrap, and thought I'd go for the traditional setup this time around.

Any input regarding this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How would it know how to reference IdentityDb though since they are
>   not coupled?

An `Id` or `UserName` value from `AspNetUsers` table would be referenced in some table in `BaseDb`. When you say "coupled", I'm assuming you're talking about a foreign key to enforce relationships between tables. You can use DataAnnotations or Fluent API to create a foreign key (which is preferable, but not necessary). But basically, anytime you get a `UserId` or `UserName` value through ASP.NET Identity, you would use that value to get/set row(s) from some table in `BaseDb`. See the code below.

> Do you mean a column in BaseDb to represent these Asp.Net values
>   without an actual relationship?

Yes a column such as `UserId` or `UserName` in a table (or tables) in the `BaseDb` database can reference the `UserId` or `UserName` column in the `AspNetUsers` database without a foreign key to enforce the relationship. However, you can use DataAnnotations or Fluent API to create a foreign key. I didn't add code for that btw.

Here is some sample code that I hope is helpful:

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=./IdentityDb.sqlite"
    "BaseConnection": "Data Source=./BaseDb.sqlite"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

**Startup.cs snippet**

```
public class Startup
{
    // ...

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ...
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDbContext<BaseDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("BaseConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddScoped<ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddScoped<BaseDbContext>();
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

**ApplicationDbContext.cs**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

**BaseDbContext.cs**

```
public class BaseDbContext : DbContext
{
    public BaseDbContext(DbContextOptions<BaseDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Member> Members { get; set; }
}
```

**Member.cs**

```
public class Member
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; } // to link with Identity

    // some other properties of Member
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Favorite> Favorites { get; set; }
}
```

Then in any of your Controller classes, you get the username of the currently logged in user from ASP.NET Identity, get username(s) in Member table of baseDb, save username in Member table of baseDb, etc.

**HomeController.cs snippet**

```
public class HomeController : Controller{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _identityContext;
    private readonly BaseDbContext _baseContext;

    public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext identityContext, BaseDbContext baseContext)
    {
        _identityContext = identityContext;
        _baseContext = baseContext;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        // get currently logged in user's username from ASP.NET Identity
        string userName = User.Identity.Name;

        // get username in Member table of baseDb where Id column is 123
        string anotherUserName = _context.Member().FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == 123).UserName;

        // add new row in basedb.Member table with identity username as foreign key
        var model = new Member
        {
            UserName = userName,
            Age = 1,
            Favorites = new List<Favorite>();
        };
        _baseContext.Add(model);
        _baseContext.SaveChanges();

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Very thorough explanation. 

What I guess I couldn't wrap my head around was the foreign-key part, which you say I can solve uising Fluent API / Data annotations. I would like to keep the columns related with relationships even if not necessary, just to get the proper structure of my databases. Do you happen to have any link to a scenario where this is used in a case like this? 

I want to thank you again for the help so far!

Comment: Since you are using two separate dbcontexts (ApplicationDbContext & BaseDbContext), which connect to two separate SQLite databases (IdentityDb.sqlite & BaseDb.sqlite), you cannot create foreign key relationship between AspNetUsers.UserName column in IdentityDb.sqlite database and Member.UserName column in BaseDb.sqlite database. SQLite's built-in foreign key constraints do not work across databases. The way to make it work would require you to store AspNetUsers table and Member table in a single SQLite database. This can be done by using the same connection string for both of the dbcontexts.

Comment: If you were to update `appsettings.json` so that there is only one ConnectionString and also update `Startup.cs` so that `ApplicationDbContext` and `BaseDbContext` both use the single connection string in `appsettings.json`, then you can create foreign key relationship between AspNetUsers.UserName column and Member.UserName column.

Comment: I see. I will probably integrate them to make it possible to have them related to each other. Thanks a lot for the thourough explanations regarding this. Really helpful, will mark your first answer as accepted!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to create a user table in your other database (BaseDb). If you want to refer to the user created by ASP.NET Identity in your IdentityDb database, you just need to reference the Id or UserName column from your AspNetUsers table in your IdentityDb database as a foreign key where it is required in your BaseDb database.

Comment: Hmmm I see. How would it know how to reference IdentityDb though since they are not coupled? Do you mean a column in BaseDb to represent these Asp.Net values without an actual relationship? Having a hard time grasping how it would be possible otherwhise. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I mean a column (such as UserId or UserName) in some table(s) in BaseDb that is a foreign key to AspNetUsers.Id or AspNetUsers.UserName. For instance, you have your ApplicationDbContext class for ASP.NET Identity (`public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> { ... }`) and your BaseDbContext class (`public class BaseDbContext : DbContext{ ... }`). Then create a model class (i.e. `public class Member`) which has a `public string UserName` property. You can then assign the value to `Member.UserName` with `User.Identity.Name`. I'll add another answer with some code.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. Yeah this was what I was thinking. This means they have no actual relationship but just point to values in the other database, right? I'm trying to keep the databases separate for the cleanest structure possible.

Comment: You have the choice to keep loose coupling by not creating a foreign key, which works fine. However, you can also choose to create a foreign key and enforce relationships between `AspNetUsers` table and whatever other table in `BaseDb` using DataAnotations or Fluent Api.

Comment: The code sample below is for ASP.NET Core MVC btw. If you find it useful, please upvote my answer and/or mark as correct solution.

Comment: I just realize that SQLite's built-in foreign key constraints do not work across databases. So yeah, loosely coupled.